# Number of hamiltonian paths in directed graph and its addition to complete digraph

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a simple directed graph and h(G) - number of hamiltonian paths in it. Let H be addition of G to complete digraph. Prove that h(G) and h(H) have the same parity. Can you give me a hint how to start, please?

Comment: What do you mean by addition of two graphs?